Error Supabase hosting: django.db.utils.OperationalError: Tenant or user not found
I am trying to host my PostgreSQL database on Supabase from my Django project. I had success a few weeks ago with the same tech stack.  I think the problem has to do with using django dotenv, but I followed the same steps and updated the same code as my last project.
The error message: django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "aws-0-us-west-1.pooler.supabase.com" (52.8.172.168), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Tenant or user not found
If I put the password directly in settings.py, it will connect to Supabase no problem but it doesn't feel secure to have the password commited to Github.
If I put the info directly into the terminal shell, I'm able to access the database and make queries no problem.
Once I use dotenv, it won't connect.
Here is the code:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()
...
'USER': str(os.getenv('SUPA_USER')),
'PASSWORD': str(os.getenv('SUPA_PW')),

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There isn't much code to provide as I am hosting the database on Supabase and that was the error log in the deployment.  It seems to not recognize the user though I connected the database in settings.py with the exact strings they provided.  I ended up fixing the issue by deleting the Supabase database, reverting to my last working commit and starting the deployment over.  I didn't change anything with the .env files and it is now up and running.

The FATAL: Tenant or user not found just means You got the postgres user wrong.
Since about 2023/2024 Supabase uses the same host/port for all projects in that AWS region, so your DB is really identified by the username.
The username should look like this: postgres.htnzmjxayxdeqrtispvf
(Tangent) I personally like to use POSTGRES_LOGIN_URL to only have to set one config - wrote a little util function for parsing that to psycopg2 connect: https://github.com/petercsiba/supawee/blob/main/supawee/client.py#L28

And if your user is 'guest' the username should look like guest.htnzmjxayxdeqrtispvf cause the later string is an identification in postgres.

I hope you solved your issue but, I encountered the same problem,
The problem in my code is that the environment is not loaded on my application. Thus we need to load the environment first before using it.
Hope it solves your problem
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


Thanks for your answer. I ended up deleting the supabase project, reverting to my last working commit and starting the deployment from the beginning.  The code was all the same, so it was a strange issue.
